# Android: SharedPreferences loses 2 of its variables after closing app

Tags: java, android

i save a couple variables via SharedPreferences without a problem. However, 2 of these variables are reset after i restart the app. I think the problem happens while saving, not while loading, because if i change the default value for loading, it doesnt even use that value, it just goes to 0.

I call this method in onPause:

```
public void saveStats() {
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES, this.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

    editor.putLong(SECONDS_PLAYED_TOTAL_FILE, secondsPlayedTotal);
    editor.putFloat(CURRENCY_GAINED_TOTAL_FILE, currencyGainedTotal);
    editor.apply();
}
```

And load onResum:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES, this.MODE_PRIVATE);
SECONDS_PLAYED_TOTAL = pref.getLong(SECONDS_PLAYED_TOTAL_FILE, 0);
CURRENCY_GAINED_TOTAL = pref.getFloat(CURRENCY_GAINED_TOTAL_FILE, 0);
```

The variables are public and static.
I save and load similar public static variables without a problem, but those 2 are the only ones i save at onPause().

Any idea?

Comment: Is your app killed after **onPause()**? You can check the process id to verify. And you wrote **if i change the default value for loading, it doesnt even use that value, it just goes to 0**. Did you mean even specify a default value like 1234, **pref.getLong(SECONDS_PLAYED_TOTAL_FILE, 1234)** always return 0?

Comment: Yea, i changed the default value to something other than 0 and it didnt load a 0. I save other stuff in onPause without a problem (they are not global variables tho).

Comment: OK, so **onPause** is successfully executed in your case. Looks weird. What about reading SharedPreferences after writing. Or after **onPause**, use "adb shell run-as [your_app_package] cat shared_prefs/[your_shared_preference_file_name]" to verify whether the value is persisted.

Comment: I have to look that up, because im actually a beginner.

Comment: It says "no such file or directory" but i probably do smth wrong, because it successfully saves a lot of other stuff.

Comment: I got it to work by loading the Value in onResume(). Those are global variables meant to show lifetime statistics of the app. I just used them as global variables in every activity without loading them before and then saved them in sharedpreferences in onPause(). I only loaded these 2 values from sharedprefs in the activity that needs to display them.That works with the others but i dont know why it doesnt work with those 2 without loading them first. The only similarity is, that these 2 values get manipulated by multiple activites and not just by 1.

Comment: Ok i realized my mistake. The only reason the other values worked, is, that i clicked the activity first, that loads them from sharedprefs in the first place, so they were up to date. But i didnt load them in the activity that actually used them. So when i go straight to those activities (that dont load them from sharedprefs), the value gets reset of course. That happened all the time with the 2 values from my question.

Answer (score 2):

You could try replacing`editor.apply();` with `editor.commit()`

From the Android documentation:

> Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to disk and you won't be notified of any failures.

Link:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()